# How to display text on a programatically created button?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've created buttons programatically, and they have a text value but for some reason don't show it.

```
Dim NodeButton As New Control    
NodeButton.Name = "Button" & NodeID   
NodeButton.BackColor = Color.Red   
NodeButton.Text = (NodeID)
```

Where `NodeID` is a variabe declared elsewhere in the program

Comment: does the button itself show up?

Comment: Change `Dim NodeButton As New Control` to `Dim NodeButton As New Button` if you want to add a button.

Comment: Yes, the button does show, just not the text

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `NodeID` in the debugger when you assign it to `NodeButton.Text`?

Comment: A `Control` is the base class, I don't think it renders any text. Use a `Button` or a `Label` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First, as already said in the comments you should change `Dim NodeButton As New Control` to `Dim NodeButton As New Button`

In second place I believe that you should add the new control to your form using something like this:

```
Me.Controls.Add(NodeButton)
```